# how to encode string so that it can be sent via http?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have this piece of string in my POST request:

```
"signature=bI�(��0�P���h;"
```

Now, i would like to encode it, since my `WebResponse` class doesn't want to send it over. I tried using `HttpUtility.HtmlEncode()`, but that method doesn't want to cooperate (I mean string stays intact).

How can i encode those weird characters so that it will go through http?

**Edit: Okay nvm, I just found out that there is also a method called .UrlEncode(), which works as intended, sorry for trouble!**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

.NET also has URL Encode: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zttxte6w.aspx or look up HttpUtility.UrlEncode

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`HttpUtility.UrlEncode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zttxte6w.aspx).

`HttpUtility.UrlEncode` - URL encoding ensures that all browsers will correctly transmit text in URL strings. Characters such as a question mark (?), ampersand (&), slash mark (/), and spaces might be truncated or corrupted by some browsers. As a result, these characters must be encoded in  tags or in query strings where the strings can be re-sent by a browser in a request string.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean "post as a form value", then that is a fairly standard thing to do. Why not let a library component worry about that:

```
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
   var vals = new NameValueCollection();
   vals["signature"] = yourString;
   // other form inputs here...
   client.UploadValues(url, "post", vals);
}
```